# Typescript + Parcel new JSX transform - React is not defined error

Tags: reactjs, jsx, parcel

I've updated to React `17+` and am now getting a `React is not defined` issue when removing
`import React from 'react'` statements from typescript TSX and JSX files.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've identified the problem is the version of a few babel plugins that are outdated that Parcel (version `2.0.0-beta.3.1` at time of writing) is using.

Here's my solution:

Add these two packages to you `package.json` file:

```
yarn add --dev @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
or
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx
```

update your babel config or create a new `.babelrc` file:

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I've created a related issue: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6389